# Missing Outlook right-click menu option

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, office365

I have a user with an issue where they go to save images embedded in an email and the only option they get is copy not save.

[image: Missing Save Button]

The original email came from a text message. When the user forwarded this email to me i experienced the same issue aswell. All images that came from a text message is having this issue

The blank spot below copy is the save button and you can click/use it but the text is missing.

I've tried a pc restart,outlook in safe mode, office repair, sfc scan, windows update and outlook update.

Would anyone know how to fix this or what causes this issue?

Comment: According to my test, this may be by design. For this kind of mail, if you'd like to save the picture in the messages, please click " Actions" button found in the Move tab and select "View In Browser" then you can save the pictures here.

Comment: @Aidan I did a test yesterday and found out the Save Button is missing in Office 365ProPlus but in office 2016 the save button is visible. could be potentially a bug since the Save butt does work its just the text is missing \_(O_O)_/